# Image button style in android

Tags: android, button

Hi am confused with image button options in android. I have created three image buttons with the following xml

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/folder_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:src="@drawable/search" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:src="@drawable/advancedsettings" 
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
```

But the out is like button with image on its ..
Please help me to show the image only as button..Thnx in advance!

Comment: use ImageView widget in place of ImageButton widget.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put this tag in your `ImageButton`

```
android:background="@null"
```

This will do it.

Comment: Oh yes it does ...thnks dear... :)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a transparent color: This will solve your problem.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```